# Typescript mapStateToProps not updating the component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I just started using typescript so pardon me if I am staring right at the solution. I have a component as follows

```
import './weatherInfo.css';

import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import IWeatherInfo from '../../models/WeatherInfo';
import {IApplicationState} from '../../reducers';
import WeatherInfo from './weatherInfoItem';

interface IWeatherInfoList{
  weatherInfoList:IWeatherInfo[]
}
class WeatherInfoList extends React.Component<IWeatherInfoList> {

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    console.log("Component will recieve props"); <------ 1
  }

   render() {
    console.log(this.props.weatherInfoList);
    return (
      <div className="weatherInfoContainer">
        {this.props.weatherInfoList.map((weatherInfoItem, index)=>{
          debugger
          return (<WeatherInfo key={index}  {...weatherInfoItem}/>);
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: IApplicationState):IWeatherInfoList {
<------- 2
    return {
      weatherInfoList: state.weatherInfo.citiesWeatherData
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {

};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WeatherInfoList);
```

state.weatherInfo.citiesWeatherData is of type IWeatherInfo[]

Now whenever I update the store state all is looking good, the store get updated. But the component doesn't get new props (hence it isn't rerendered). So I put a break point at 2 and 1. It stops at 2 but not at 1. I tried changing the type of weatherInfoList to a string array and then it is working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried removing the debugger from `this.props.weatherInfoList.map`? It might be the application getting stuck inside the render method

Comment: Yeah I removed it that is not the issue.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` was renamed to [`UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), and it will be removed in the future. Try using [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) instead.